# SQL Server trigger execution in batch updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to know about how the trigger execution happens for the below scenario.

I have 20 records in a table and I have an `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` trigger on that table. When I'm updating all the records in that table using a `MERGE` or batch update statement, how will the trigger execute?

Does it execute for each row by row?

Or is it executing once per a batch (once for all 20 records)?

If it is execute once per batch do we need to write a loop inside the trigger to perform a task for each row?

Comment: Generally, you should try to avoid writing loops in SQL - the natural way to work is in terms of *sets* of rows. That's as true inside a trigger as anywhere else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Triggers in SQL Server **always** execute **once per batch** - there's no option for "for each row" triggers in SQL Server.

When you mass-update your table, the trigger will receive **all** the updated rows at once in the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables and needs to deal with them accordingly - as a **set of data** - not a single row

Comment: Then If I need to write the updated data to another table, If I write `Insert Into SomeTable SELECT * FROM UPDATED` ,Will it copy all the updated data to the other table? @marc_s

Comment: @tarzanbappa: almost - the trigger has two "pseudo" tables - `inserted` and `deleted`. In the case of an `UPDATE` statement, the `deleted` contains the old values (before the `UPDATE`), and the `inserted` contains the new values. There's no `updated` pseudo table

Comment: sorry I've mistaken, so If it is `Insert Into SomeTable SELECT * FROM DELETED`,Will it copy all the updated data to the other table? @marc_s

Comment: @tarzanbappa: no - the `deleted` table holds the **OLD** data - before the `UPDATE` - not the updated data - that's in `inserted`. Which data do you need - the old one (for archiving) ? Use `select * from deleted`. Or the new one *AFTER* the `UDPATE` - then use `select * from inserted`